# Build/Rebuild a full history Type-2 Table from source data

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in a PSA where I am capturing changes to records in a source table.  Let's say it looks like this:

```
+-----+------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| PK  | Check_cols | Dont_care_cols |     start_ts     |      end_ts      |
+-----+------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| 123 | abc        | def            | 1/1/20 00:10:00  | 1/2/20 13:13:23  |
| 123 | abc        | dhf            | 1/2/20 13:13:23  | 1/3/20 04:21:00  |
| 123 | abc        | dhz            | 1/3/20 04:21:00  | 1/5/20 12:15:00  |
| 123 | abd        | dyz            | 1/5/20 12:15:00  | 1/9/20 15:16:00  |
| 123 | abc        | dyz            | 1/9/20 15:16:00  | null             |
| 456 | ghi        | jkl            | 1/2/20 03:45:00  | 1/10/20 00:00:00 |
| 456 | lmn        | opq            | 1/10/20 00:00:00 | null             |
+-----+------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I would like to build a type-2 dimension (tracks changes with record start and stop times) from that table using only the values of check_cols, like the one shown below.  I am looking for a pure SQL solution, with no looping.

check_cols is comprised of multiple columns, but I will use a md5 hash to look for changes.  Since my dimension only cares about check_cols there are situations where the timestamp records aren't what I need.  For instance if a value in the dont_care_cols changes, but none of the check_cols values change.

From the data above, I want the following result set:

```
+-----+------------+------------------+------------------+
| PK  | Check_cols |     start_ts     |      end_ts      |
+-----+------------+------------------+------------------+
| 123 | abc        | 1/1/20 00:10:00  | 1/5/20 12:15:00  |
| 123 | abd        | 1/5/20 12:15:00  | 1/9/20 15:16:00  |
| 123 | abc        | 1/9/20 15:16:00  | null             |
| 456 | ghi        | 1/2/20 03:45:00  | 1/10/20 00:00:00 |
| 456 | lmn        | 1/10/20 00:00:00 | null             |
+-----+------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I've tried using window functions to compare lead and lag values, get mins and maxes, etc, but I can't figure out this edge case shown for PK 123 in the first table.  I also have not found a solution via google/stackoverflow/etc.  Most methods rely on daily snapshots running.  I want to be able to rebuild the target table if I have a logic change. Anyone have thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best answer or whether it solves all of your use-cases, but give it a try and let me know if there is an edge case that stumbles over it.  It's a bit of a hack.  Also, I did add a few records to the use-case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE tran_data (pk int, check_cols varchar, dont_care_cols varchar, start_ts timestamp, end_ts timestamp);

INSERT INTO tran_data
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(123,'abc','def',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/20 00:10:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/2/20 13:13:23','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (123,'abc','dhf',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/2/20 13:13:23','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/3/20 04:21:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (123,'abc','dhz',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/3/20 04:21:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/5/20 12:15:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (123,'abd','dyz',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/5/20 12:15:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/9/20 15:16:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (123,'abd','dyz',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/9/20 15:16:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/11/20 14:14:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (123,'abc','dyz',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/11/20 14:14:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/14/20 09:14:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (123,'abc','dyz',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/14/20 09:14:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),null),
              (456,'ghi','jkl',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/2/20 03:45:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),TO_TIMESTAMP('1/10/20 00:00:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss')),
              (456,'lmn','opq',TO_TIMESTAMP('1/10/20 00:00:00','MM/DD/YY hh:mi:ss'),null)
        );
```

From there, I tried to find a way to create "groups" using a method that I hope will stand up to all of your use-cases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     PK
   , check_cols
   , FIRST_VALUE(start_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY PK, check_cols, group_num ORDER BY start_ts) as new_start_ts
   , LAST_VALUE(end_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY PK, check_cols, group_num ORDER BY start_ts) as new_end_ts
FROM (
  SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PK, check_cols ORDER BY start_ts) as group_cnt
     , group_cnt - pk_row as group_num
     , *
  FROM (
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PK ORDER BY start_ts) as pk_row
       , IFNULL(LAG(check_cols) OVER (PARTITION BY PK ORDER BY start_ts),check_cols) as prev_check_cols
       , *
    FROM tran_data
    )
  )
ORDER BY pk, new_start_ts;
```

Comment: Very creative solution.  At the moment I can't think of any cases outside of this.  If you think of any, please post back!

Comment: For anyone curious about the Kung Fu here, I'll give it a shot.  This SQL orders the sequence of all records for a PK using pk_row, then orders the sequence of records whose values are the same using grp_cnt, then says any rows with same values that are grouped together in the PK sequence will have the same value for [grp_cnt - pk_row], finally this lets you take the first start_ts and last end_ts for those groups. And...I'm fairly certain I wouldn't have thought of that.  Thanks.